# SSD in a 2012 17" causing GPU failures?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, power, gpu

Just got my MBP back from Apple after taking it in with GPU overheating glitches. Apparently this model (2012) are prone to it and it's been exhibiting all the symptoms. Blue screens, grey screens, weird graphics, boots failures etc.

However and too my surprise, Apple have blamed the Samsung EVO 1 TB SSD I had put in a few weeks prior to the glitches starting. They say its the power drain of the SSD that is causing the glitches.

SO I've now put the original HDD back and and am seeing if the problems return. It took a few boots (SMC, PRAM resets) with failures after reinstalling it before I could get a fresh install of OS X in and now I'll waiting to see if it starts up again.

Would like to know if anyone else has had a SSD installed which has then interfered with the GPU? or is Apple feeding me a line?

Comment: true story that some ssds can take more power and give more heat than rotational drives.  as far as your case, i'm not sure.  have you been monitoring the different temperatures in your mbp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All resolved. MBP started playing up again without a few hours. GPU overheating and corrupting the display.

Took it back to Apple again and this time they replace the logic board. MBP is now running noticeably cooler with no issues. Have reinstalled the SSD without any problems.